# Meld fails to start after upgrading to 10.13 high-sierra

Tags: macos, meld, macos-high-sierra

Meld fails to start after upgrading to the 10.13 osx version (high sierra).

How do I fix this?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.  Apple questions are on topic over at [apple.se].

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I deleted the alias `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Frameworks/libz.1.dylib` and now it works.

Comment: for lazy people: `unlink /Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Frameworks/libz.1.dylib`

Comment: This works, by the what is reason i can't understand. Is this library not available in mac os high sierra?

Comment: There is also now an updated meldmerge.dmg at https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/ that fixed it for me.